# Geração de restrição distinta para elemento e seu atributo - XSD

Tags: xml, atributos, xsd

Bom dia!
Tenho o seguinte elemento em um XML:
`<estcivil unestavel="S">C</estcivil>`

Acontece que meu atributo só pode receber valores "S" ou "N", mas o elemento tem outras restrições de valores, como: "C","S","D","V".
Como poderia gerar essas duas restrições no Schema XSD, uma para o elemento e outra para o atributo?.

Meu XSD está assim:

```
<xs:element name="estcivil" maxOccurs="1" ref="ESTCIV">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
   <xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="unestavel" use="required">
     <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="S|N"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
   </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

sendo o ESTCIV:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ESTCIV">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="D"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="P"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="U"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="V"/>         
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Obrigado.